# Input field is not displaying

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to horizontally align `input` and `img` elements that are in a particular `div`. I have given `input` element a CSS property of `display:block` but my Firebug is showing its display property as `none`.

REGARDING CSS

```
.block_feedback .field input {
    color: #FFF;
    width:375px;
    height:17px; line-height:17px;
    margin-left:15px; margin-top:6px;
    display:block;
    background-color:transparent;
    border:0px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
    float:left; 
 }
.block_feedback .field img { 
    color:#F00; 
    width:27px;
    height:27px; line-height:25px;
    margin-left:405px; margin-top:0px;
    display:block;
    background-color:transparent; 
    border:0px; 
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold; 
    font-weight:bold;
    float:left;
 }
```

HTML

```
<div class="field">
    <input type="text" name="name" class="w_def_text" title="Name*" />
    <img width="27" height="27" src="images/error.jpg" alt="Error"> 
</div>
```

Firebug is showing as

```
 <input class="w_def_text" type="password" title="Password*" name="password" style="display: none;">jQuery1510542302776850034=Object { olddisplay="block"}
 <img width="27" height="27" alt="Error" src="images/error.jpg" style="display: block;">
 <span style="display: none;">Password*</span>jQuery1510542302776850034=Object { olddisplay="block"}
```

jQuery

```
function init_fields() {
$('.w_def_text').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).attr('title');
    var html = '<span>' + text + '</span>';
    $(this).parent().append(html);

    if($(this).val() == '') {
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).next().show();
    }
    else {
        $(this).css({'display' : 'block'});
        $(this).next().hide();
    }
});

$('.w_def_text').live('blur', function() {
    if($(this).val() == '') {
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).next().show();
    }
});

$('.w_def_text ~ span').live('click', function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).prev().css({'display' : 'block'}).focus();
});
}
```

Comment: Looks as if jQuery is hiding it. Share your JavaScript?

Comment: The jquery bits in your firebug sample there would seem to indicate that you've got some JS somewhere playing with the css behind your back.

Comment: @Marc but I don't think my jquery is modifying any of display property.

Comment: .hide() does change the display property... You're doing it quite a few times in the JS you've posted.

Comment: So what _exactly_ is your question and what are you trying to achieve here?  You're clearly changing the display of the input element to `none` with one of those `.hide()`'s in your jQuery.  If you don't believe it, simply disable your JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve but based on your question title and brief description, it seems that you simply don't know why your input element is hidden or why it's `display: none` in Firebug.

It seems pretty clear that it's being changed to `display: none` in your jQuery code by the  `.hide()` method.

As per the [jQuery documention](http://api.jquery.com/hide/):

> With no parameters, the `.hide()` method is the simplest way to hide an element:
>
> `$('.target').hide();`
>
> The matched elements will be
>   hidden immediately, with no animation. **This is roughly equivalent to
>   calling `.css('display', 'none')`**

Without seeing the rest of your HTML markup or knowing the purpose of your script, it's impossible to say which line containing `.hide()` is causing it.  Simply disable your JavaScript as proof to yourself that the jQuery code is the root cause.